# I'm trying to make a login system, everything works fine, but nothing shows up in the text file

Tags: python

I'm very new to python, but I wanted to test how far I could go. I am just trying to make a simple login system, and I am almost done, the only thing is that nothing shows up in the text file after the user makes an account. No errors, but this code will accept anything, and doesn't check if there is a certain username/password in the text file. I just need some help, and I know this is very sloppy, but anything will be appreciated. This is the code so far:

```
correct_username = False
correct_password = False

def check_file(file_name,username,password):
    with open(file_name, 'r') as read_obj:
        for line in read_obj:
            if username and password in line:
                return True
    return False

def login():
    loginInfo = check_file('Data_Storage.txt', username=input('Username: '), 
    password=input('Password: '))
    if loginInfo:
        print("You have successfully logged in!")

def write():
    enter_data = open('Data_Storage.txt', 'a')
    enter_data.write('Username: ' + username)
    enter_data.write('Password: ' + password)
    enter_data.write('')
    enter_data.close()


have_account = input("Do you have an account (Y/N): ")

if have_account == 'N' or have_account == 'n':
    curate_account = input("Would you like to make one (Y/N): ")
    if curate_account == 'Y' or curate_account == 'y':
        username = input('Username: ')
        password = input('Password: ')
        write()
        loginuwu = input("You're all set, would you like to log in (Y/N): ")
        if loginuwu == 'Y' or loginuwu == 'y':
            login()
elif have_account == 'Y' or have_account == 'y':
    login()

else:
    pass
```

Comment: You are writing all the login infos into a single line in the file. Could that be the problem? Also, `if username and password in line:` does not what you think it does. Basically you are checking that the username is not empty and the password is anywhere in the single-line file. Apart from that, it seems to work and the file is created (with a single line, see above).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Writing to the text file actually should work, but `write` does not automatically add a linebreak, so all the credentials end up in the same line. But there are a few more problems:

- as already said, you write all the usernames and passwords into the same line of the file without any linebreaks; you have to explicitly add `"\n"` when calling `write`
- the line `if username and password in line:` is *not* "both username and password are in the same line" but instead "username is not empty and password is in the line"
- but even if you fix that, the `in` check is not appropriate here: if you just check `username in line and password in line`, the user could just enter `""` for both and would be able to log in; instead, you should compare with the *full* usernames and passwords from the file<sup>1</sup>
- since you do not know what characters are in the username or password (especially in the latter) it is not easy to define a specific separator character to store them on the same line, so I'd suggest storing them on alternating lines (a linebreak is the one thing the user can not enter in `input`) and using `next` when iterating the lines of the file to get the password corresponding to a username (here, you have to use `strip` to *remove* the linebreaks)

Also, some more possible improvements:

- you can `lower` the user input so you don't have to check whether it matches `Y` or `y`
- you could make another function for getting the credentials and store the filename in a variable

Try the following version:

```
filename = 'Data_Storage.txt'

def ask_credentials():
    return input('Username: '), input('Password: ')

def login():
    username, password = ask_credentials()
    if check_file(username, password):
        print("You have successfully logged in!")
    else:
        print("Login failed")

def check_file(username,password):
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        for usr in map(str.strip, f):
            pwd = next(f).strip()
            if usr == username and pwd == password:
                return True
    return False

def create_account():
    username, password = ask_credentials()
    with open(filename, 'a') as f:
        f.write(username + "\n")
        f.write(password + "\n")

have_account = input("Do you have an account (Y/N): ").lower()
if have_account == 'n':
    if input("Would you like to make one (Y/N): ").lower() == 'y':
        create_account()
        if input("You're all set, would you like to log in (Y/N): ").lower() == 'y':
            login()
elif have_account == 'y':
    login()
```

---

<sup>1)</sup> Of course, you should *not* do this in practice, either. This is still a very bad and insecure way of storing and checking usernames and passwords, but probably a bit better than it was before.